# How to use OFFSET in SOSL DYNAMIC

Tags: apex, dynamic-soql

I need to use the offset 0 in my Dynamic SOSL, but giving me unexpected token error:-
kindly help me out for the below issue
CODE :-

```
jsdhfksjfjsa;fk;alskd;lasx;;,;lms;dm;ksddmc;lsdlmc;lsdc;l;m
```

Error :-
exceptionType":"System.QueryException","isUserDefinedException":false,"message":"unexpected token: offset","stackTrace":"

Answer (score 2):

According to the [documentation on OFFSET in SOSL](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.soql_sosl.meta/soql_sosl/sforce_api_calls_sosl_offset.htm)

> OFFSET can be used only when querying a single object. OFFSET must be the last clause specified in a query

`OFFSET` is part of the `RETURNING` clause, so it needs to appear inside the parenthesis for `Investment_Capability_Reference__c`.

wrong:

```
'AND Available_for_selection__c = true ORDER BY Fund_Name__c)'+' offset';
```

correct:

```
// Note that we need to ensure there is a space between the ordered field
//   and the OFFSET clause
'AND Available_for_selection__c = true ORDER BY Fund_Name__c ' + offset + ')';
```

There also doesn't appear to be much reason to make this query dynamic, given the context we have. [SOSL supports variable binds in the `FIND`, `WHERE`, and `OFFSET` clauses](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/langCon_apex_SOQL_variables.htm).

```
// Assuming that offsetInteger is literally an integer
// i.e. 0, 100, 2000 (2000 is the max offset)
//   and not "OFFSET 0"
[FIND :sampleSearchText 
RETURNING Investment_Capability_Reference__c(
    <fields here> 
    WHERE (Structure__c LIKE :sample OR ...) 
    OFFSET :offsetInteger
)];
```

Comment: Not Sure ,, still getting the same issue.